# Передать в обработчик данные собранные с формы, и с обработчика отдать ответ равный 1 или 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Сделал форму добавления отзыва к товару.
Прикрутил защита от csrf.

В js собираю данные с формы serialize(), и отдаю их в ajax.

В обработчике перед там как добавить данные в БД, с начала проверяю токен, если токен совпадает, то добавляю данные, если нет то возвращаю ответ 0 и останавливаю скрипт.

Если в ajax если все успешно, то вывожу success modal.

Теперь хочу сделать в ajax, если возвращается 0 то вывести окно об ошибке токена, и не выводить success modal. Как это сделать?

Кстати, в форме сделал hidden input с value=0. И в обработчике в последствии присваиваю ему значение 0 либо 1. Сейчас не получается отправить его обратно в ответ в ajax и проверить там и от его значение делать результат во frontend.

Надеюсь я смог донести мысль. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту задачу.

Вот код:

```
$.ajax({
            url: $("#rv_ajax_form").attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
                if ( 1 ){
                    $(".rv-success-main").css({"display" : "block"});

                    $(".mymodal").css({"display" : "none"}).fadeOut();
                } else alert("error");

            },

            error: function(response) {
                alert("Ошибка отправки, попробуйте позже.");
            }
        });
```

Вот php:

```
$sessid = bitrix_sessid();
if ( $_POST['sessid'] != $sessid ) {
    $_POST['isStatus'] = 0;
    echo $_POST['isStatus'];
    die();
} else {
    $_POST['isStatus'] = 1;
    echo $_POST['isStatus'];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: $("#rv_ajax_form").attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.status){
            alert('success')
            $(".rv-success-main").css({"display" : "block"});

            $(".mymodal").css({"display" : "none"}).fadeOut();
        } else alert("error");

    },

    error: function(response) {
        alert("Ошибка отправки, попробуйте позже.");
    }
});



$sessid = bitrix_sessid();

if ( $_POST['sessid'] != $sessid ) {
    $_POST['isStatus'] = 0;
    echo json_encode(['status' => true]); exit;
} else {
    $_POST['isStatus'] = 1;
    echo json_encode(['status' => false]); exit;
};
```

Comment: `exit;die();` Еще `__halt_compiler()` добавьте, чтоб уж наверняка.

Comment: alert( data.status ), выдает undefined

Comment: Вот что приходит в data:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> Т.е. это не json объект

Comment: уберите комментарий с  dataType: "json",

Comment: если ставлю dataType: "json", то срабатывает секция: error: function(data) {
                    alert("Ошибка отправки, попробуйте позже.");
                }

Comment: а что вы в data отправляете ?

Comment: var data = $("#rv_ajax_form").serialize();

Comment: Сейчас пробую так: `var formdata = $("#rv_ajax_form").serializeArray();
            var data = {};
            $(formdata).each( function(index, obj) {
                data[obj.name] = obj.value;
            });`

Comment: в ajax:  `data: data,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,`

Comment: @madfan41k <br> в ajax  `success: function( response ) {
                    alert(response.status);
                    if ( response.status ){
                        $(".rv-success-main").css({"display" : "block"});

                        $(".mymodal").css({"display" : "none"}).fadeOut();
                    } else alert("error");

                }`

Comment: @madfan41k     Но отрабатывает вот это блок:   `error: function(response) {
                    alert("Ошибка отправки, попробуйте позже.");
                }`